# Blank screen at stacksnippets at chromium 54

Tags: bug

Blank screen at stacksnippets at chromium 54. Is this a known bug?

[image]

Comment: What's the corresponding snippet?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not certain what you mean?

Comment: Is there some corresponding snippet code that generates the blank screen?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No. The resulting window depicted at Question is entire result when clicking `Ctrl-M` at an Answer.

Comment: No...you click the Snippet icon and there's no sections to enter code. Reproduced in Chrome 54.0.2840.34 beta-m (64-bit) on W10.